# CString ToString() template overload for CppUnitTestFramework

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mstest

How do you write a C++ VS2012 CppUnitTestFramework ToString() template overload for CStrings? It must be possible.

The compiler says I must as it gives the compilation error:

```
error C2338: Test writer must define specialization of ToString<const Q& q> for your class class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > __cdecl Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString<class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > >>(const class ATL::CStringT<unsigned short,class StrTraitMFC<unsigned short,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<unsigned short> > > &).
```

Noramlly for other data types I add something similar to this to my unit test code:

```
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
namespace Microsoft { namespace VisualStudio { namespace CppUnitTestFramework {
    template<> static std::wstring ToString<eNumy>(const eNumy & e) {   return ltots(static_cast<long>(e)); }
```

I have tried adding:

```
template<> static std::wstring ToString<CString>(const CString & e) { return e.GetBuffer(); }
```

But that fails to compile with const issues:

```
error C2663: 'ATL::CSimpleStringT<BaseType>::GetBuffer' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
```

Anyone got any ideas?

I want to run this test:

```
CString csTina;
CString csGeoff;
Assert::AreNotEqual(csTina, csGeoff);
```

Comment: Any chance that `GetBuffer` is not a `const` function?

Comment: Furthermore, if you want to return `std::wstring` you might want to overload for `CStringW` really.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=vs-2017#getbuffer) you have it:
`CString`'s function `GetBuffer` is not marked as `const` function, thus you cannot invoke this function on `const CString&`.

Multiple options:

- Remove the `const` from the overload.
- Implement the logic without `GetBuffer`.
- Do a `const_cast` to obtain it. (*NOT* recommended though).
- Simply convert the `CString` to `std::string` (or `std::wstring`) and use the existing functionality.

Comment: Excellent answer! Convert to std::wstring works a treat. Thanks.